# How to simplify this in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Is there a shorter way in Kotlin to write the following code:

```
private fun getMonth(monthText: String): Int {
    var x = arrayOf("january", "february", "jumper").indexOf(monthText)

    if (x >= 0)
        return x

    x = arrayOf("Januari", "Februari", "Maret").indexOf(monthText)

    if (x >= 0)
        return x

    throw Exception("Not found")

}
```

I have to repeat the array search for many languages and want to avoid having to repeat duplicate code. Note: The returned value must indicate the month.

Comment: And you can not or do not want to use an existing Date/Time library?

Comment: I might consider that but I doubt I will find one that includes support for a language like Tagalog. Also I doubt that a library exists that takes a date in some language and generates a Date/Time object. Usually they work the other way around.

Comment: Why `x > 0` ? The indices of the array are 0 based. The item can be found at position 0.

Comment: @forpas Oops, I corrected that. Thanks.

Comment: why do you perform a search on a `monthText`? I guess the user pick the month from an adapter from which you can have the position right away?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For performance reasons, you should better hash than search

```
private val monthByName = mapOf(
    "january" to 0,
    "february" to 1,
    "jumper" to 2,
    "Januari" to 0,
    "Februari" to 1,
    "Maret" to 2
)

private fun getMonth(monthText: String) = monthByName[monthText] ?: throw NoSuchElementException(monthText)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the nicest way:

I first build a set with all possible mappings of month to index. I define the lists and process them with `mapIndexed` to get the index value. Afterwards I flatten those to get a set with `Pair<String, Int>`

```
val monthsToIndex by lazy {
        val lists = listOf(
                arrayOf("january", "february", "jumper"),
                arrayOf("Januari", "Februari", "Maret")
        );
        lists.map { it.mapIndexed { i, s -> s to i } }.flatten().toSet()
    };
```

The Search is now a `find` in that set + a null check to throw the exception:

```
private fun getMonth(monthText: String): Int {
        return monthsToIndex.find { it.first == monthText }?.second ?: throw Exception("Not found")
    }
```

A benefit of that approach would be a very concise place where you initialise all values - and only once.

**Update:**

You can also convert this into a map as Frank Neblung has suggested - this would definitely speed up the search:

```
val monthsToIndex by lazy {
    val lists = listOf(
        arrayOf("january", "february", "jumper"),
        arrayOf("Januari", "Februari", "Maret")
    );
    lists.map { it.mapIndexed { i, s -> s to i } }.flatten().toMap()
};

private fun getMonth(monthText: String): Int {
    return monthsToIndex[monthText] ?: throw Exception("Not found")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With an array of arrays:

```
private fun getMonth(monthText: String): Int {
    val array = arrayOf(
        arrayOf("january", "february", "jumper"),
        arrayOf("Januari", "Februari", "Maret")
    )
    val months = array.firstOrNull { it.contains(monthText) }
    if (months != null) return months.indexOf(monthText)
    throw Exception("Not found")
}
```

The only inefficiency of this I can think of is that the array where `monthText` will be found, is scanned twice: once with `contains()` and then with `indexOf()`.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably hold some lists (or maps) containing your month texts and iterate over them, e.g.:

```
val englishMonths = sequenceOf("January", "February", "March" /*, ... */).mapIndexed { index, s -> s to index }.toMap()
val xxxMonths = sequenceOf("january", "february", "jumper"/*, ... */).mapIndexed { index, s -> s to index }.toMap()
// and all the other month mappings you need
```

Maybe you want to put those in an appropriate locale-mapping as well.

And your actual function would then just iterate over them:

```
fun getMonth(monthText : String) = sequenceOf(
  // all the month lists that are relevant:
  englishMonths, xxxMonths /*, ... */
)
  .mapNotNull { it[monthText] }
  .firstOrNull()
```

Which now would return `null` if no match was found. You can also just add `?: throw WhateverExceptionSuites()` if you do not like a nullable type there.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this would work (Note: For brevity I only listed 3 months for 2 languages. There are in fact 12 months for multiple languages):

```
private fun getMonth(monthText: String): Int {
    var x = arrayOf("january", "february", "march", "jumper", "Januari", "Februari", "Maret").indexOf(monthText)

    if (x < 0)
        throw Exception("Month not found")

    return (x % 12) + 1

}
```

Comment: did you know that there are countries that do have more than 12 months? ;-)

Comment: @Roland I just googled it and Ethiopia appears to be the only country with 13 months. I can handle that exception although Ethiopia is not required in code. Strangely, Tagalog is.

Comment: that's why I would recommend any date/time API before trying to implement something from scratch... if that's just a simple list that contains some month names, that will probably be ok to... but I would at least put that array outside of the function... otherwise you create it and discard it again... and that on each call...

Comment: I know of Ethiopia... but I wouldn't be surprised if there are a lot more ;-)

Comment: well... it mainly depends now on which calendars you want to support... it seems that depending on the calendar, some have a 13th month in leap years...

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
private fun getMonth(monthText: String): Int {
   val a =  arrayOf("january", "february", "jumper")
   val b = arrayOf("Januari", "Februari", "Maret")

   val result = a.zip(b)
            .mapIndexed{idx, it -> if (it.first == monthText || it.second == monthText) idx else null }
            .mapNotNull{it}.firstOrNull()
   return result ?: throw Exception("Not found")
}
```